# Android Studio suggests wrong version for a depedency

Tags: maven, android-studio

I am using Apache Commons-Net, which latest version is 3.6. I get the dependency from the Maven repository, see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net/3.6). When I get the dependency like this

```
implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'
```

it suggest that there is a new version available `20030805.205232`, which is from 2005, see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net/20030805.205232).

I currently work around this warning using a variable like this

```
implementation "commons-net:commons-net:$commons_net_version"
```

and it still suggest the update in the `Project: Structure` view in Android Studio, just not in the `build.gradle` file.

How can I disable this warning or, preferably, fix this issue, since it should not suggest a version from 2005 in the first place?